# Perform Operation on Named Capture Group in regex.Replace

Tags: c#, regex

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate--- I can't imagine that it hasn't been asked before- but I couldn't seem to find it.

Why does the 2nd c# statement below throw an exception?

```
var regex = new Regex(@"\[IMG(?<image_number>[0-9]+)\]");
regex.Replace("[IMG1]", int.Parse("${image_number}").ToString());
```

I know I can access the named group, but I can't perform an operation on it-- in this case int.Parse(). When I try to use the named group in this way, it just gives me the string "${image_number}"-- which of course can't be parsed as an integer.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Regex` class is not magic.

It cannot magically insert the captured value in string literals that appear inside `Replace` calls.
Instead, if you pass a string referencing a capture group *to the `Replace()` method*, it will parse out the string and insert the value.

You need to [pass a lambda expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cft8645c.aspx):

```
regex.Replace("[IMG1]", m => int.Parse(m.Groups["image_number"].Value).ToString());
```

Comment: Thanks man-- didn't know I could do that. Although I had to do m.Groups["image_number"].Value.